# Helm not able finding local charts to update the dependency

Tags: local, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kube-state-metrics

I am installing Prometheus on my vanilla k8s cluster using helm 3. Prometheus comes with kube-state-metrics chart dependency.
My machine is completely locked out from internet so all my development is local.
I have installed chart museum which does have my repos. But when I try to update the dependency, its not able to find it, either from local path to chart.yaml or chart-museum url.

```
Save error occurred:  directory charts/kube-state-metrics not found
Deleting newly downloaded charts, restoring pre-update state
Error: directory charts/kube-state-metrics not found
```

I have tried most of the solutions, nothing have worked so far.

Comment: Have you pointed the local chart directory location in your Chart.yaml? If not please do it by `repository: file://../kube-state-metrics`(update path accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue. The chart was linking with dependencies but regardless still gave this error.

I did mention the repo in my requirements yaml as file://./path-to-chart, but on dependency update it still prompted that error message and did not make the requirements.lock file.

The Prometheus pod was in crashloopbackoff and I thought the reason was the dependency, but from the logs it was due to permissions on the persistence volume.

Helm can do more to chart the on-premise workflows regardless. Not many software houses have open access to the internet.